# Oracle SKEWONLY & AUTO => MIXED => FOR ALL COLUMN SIZE

Tags: oracle

`SKEWONLY` is better for determine `full table VS index scan`.

`AUTO` is better for `join multiple table`.

Is there any way for `gather statistics` mixed mode `(SKEWONLY & AUTO)`?

Comment: Where did you get those statements from? The only difference between the histograms created from these are what triggers them - skew only tells Oracle to look at the data distribution and decide whether it’s skewed or not, auto does the same but then only creates the histogram if your workload references them in a way that might benefit. You will find that both will give you more histograms than necessary, if you know your data and your queries then you should know what columns really need histograms (there won’t be many).

Comment: I examine this: http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_histograms.htm link. In our databases there is approxy 1200 table with more than 600 million data per database (At multiple point for customers). And I don't know all tables, all modules, but I am trying to increase performance from multiple way when I have time. Sometimes from db, sometimes from app.

Comment: A lot of that post is just misleading (a similar thing can be said for many articles on that site), some of it is plain wrong (maybe with further explanation it might be semi-okay). You have two choices if you want to do it the easy way - use AUTO so that Oracle creates histograms where it thinks the data is skewed and your queries would use them (you will end up with more histograms than you need so some of your queries will be unnecessarily sensitive to bind input). Use size 1 everywhere and check for long queries that are slow because they need a histogram, add it manually